# MYSQL one field list of content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my table looks like this

```
username  clientname     date         time          publishedapp
 akirk     hplaptop1      30/07/2015   8:42:30.04    PB Desktop service
 akirk     hplaptop1      30/07/2015   8:40:30.04    Chrome
 akirk     hplaptop1      30/07/2015   8:40:20.04    desktop@Work2-1
 akirk     hplaptop1      30/07/2015   8:40:20.04    Powerplan
 john      dellPC1        27/07/2015   9:41:30.04    desktop@Work2-1
 john      dellPC1        27/07/2015   9:41:30.04    Word 2013
 karl      delllaptop2    27/07/2015   9:40:21.00    Chrome
 karl      delllaptop2    27/07/2015   9:40:21.00    Desktop with acrobat
 jdoe      HPPC1          27/07/2015   9:40:15.00    Powerplan
```

I want to get out put on the formar

```
Username:
  List of apps/software
```

In some circumstances the list will be filtered to contain user that user certain desktop and more than one app so i would like to get something like this on return

Users using desktop@Work2-1 and at least one app

```
User akirk
apps chrome, powerplan

User John
apps word 2013

...
```

Users using more than one app

```
User akirk
apps chrome, powerplan

...
```

User using desktop@Work2-1 and other desktops

```
User akirk
desktops PB Desktop service

...
```

Any ideas on how to start with this?

Im using PHP, and im thinking one query per user then php to do the rest? would this be possible?

## EDIT:

I've tried GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
$conn->query("SET group_concat_max_len = 2048");

$sql = "SELECT username,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publishedapp SEPARATOR \",\")
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY username
";
```

but im getting
[image]

My PHP

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $result->num_rows; $i++) {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  //echo $i .".- ". $name1 = $row["username"];
  echo $i .".- ". $name1 = $row["username"] ." ". $app1 = $row["publishedapp"];
  echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that your database table contains multiple (space separated) values in the `publishedapp` field?

Comment: It one value, just a string with the name of the app...

Comment: `select user, group_concat(app) ... group by user`, but note that group_concat() is length-limited (1024 chars by default), so for a long list, you can/will truncate the results.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with group_concat as recomended it was just missing the as part to be able to call it from PHP...

Query

```
$sql = "SELECT username,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publishedapp SEPARATOR \"<br>\") AS publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY username
";
```

PHP

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $result->num_rows; $i++) {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  //echo $i .".- ". $name1 = $row["username"];
  //echo $i .".- ". $name1 = $row["username"] ." ". $app1 = $row["publishedapp"];
  echo $i .".- ". $name1 = $row["username"];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $app1 = $row["publishedapp"];
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you just need one query and then for each returned row you can store the published app in a variable, comma separated:

```
$apps = "";

//Where you are retrieving your sql data
$apps .= $your_returned_data . ", ";
```

Then just echo $apps and you will have a list of comma seperated apps :)

Shouldn't of said one query per user (typo). You just need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename GROUP BY username
```

Comment: would you advise to get list of users on an array, iterate the array with the query to get the apps I suppose...

Comment: As Marc B said in the comments, you can group the query by the user. I've updated my post.